# Specialize template of templated data type

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have this situation:

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
T f() { return T(); }

template<>
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> f<std::vector<T>>() {
    return { T() };
}

int main(){
    f<std::vector<int>>();
}
```

I'm trying to specialize the template for `std::vector<T>`, but I'm getting this error:

```
error: too many template-parameter-lists

std::vector<T> f<std::vector<T>>() {
```

How can I specialize for `std::vector<T>`?

Comment: Partial specialisation for template functions is not allowed.

Comment: That the case I prefer tag dispatching: `template<>struct Tag{}; template<typename T>
T f(tag<T>) {/*..*/} template<typename T>
std::vector<T> f(tag<std::vector<T>>) {/*..*/}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no such thing as partially specialized function templates. What you are doing is creating a new template, so the correct syntax would be:

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> f() {
    return { T() };
}
```

This overloads the function name `f` and the two templates are independent. But by having both overloads will make almost all calls to `f` ambiguous including the one example in your `main()`.

EDIT:

Had you removed the `template<>` line which would be invalid for class partial specializations too then clang generates more helpful error message:

> error: non-class, non-variable partial specialization `f<std::vector<T,std::allocator<_Tp1> > >` is not allowed
>
> ```
> std::vector<T> f<std::vector<T>>() {
> ```

Answer (score 6):

If a problem is X, and a solution is Y, then usually specialization of function templates is Z. That's when specialization is possible anyway. You can't partially specialize function templates, only overload them.

A solution here would be to use a helper. A class template, which you *can* specialize, that will do the work. Meanwhile the function template only forwards to it.

```
namespace detail {
    template<typename T>
    struct f {
        static T work() { return T(); }
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct f<std::vector<T>> {
        static std::vector<T> work() { return {T()}; }
    };
}

template<typename T>
T f() { return detail::f<T>::work(); }
```